# What is the name of this pool or irrigation part?

Tags: pool, irrigation

[image]

Currently in a swimming pool shed. A distributor?
This device takes water in the top, and outputs it alternately to one of five pipes at the bottom. When working it makes a clockwork sound. There are plastic gears inside.
When I know what it is called then I can get parts for a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a zone indexing valve. They are commonly found on sprinkler systems to route the water to different areas. the design changes a lot so if you can find a brand name, it will help getting parts. Worse case scenario, you will have to replace the valve with a new one. good luck and stay safe out there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, junk keeps getting in this one..

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler if junk keeps getting in then fit a filter before that device...

Comment: Have done, but haven't finished training the guy who takes it off to "vacuum" the pool. He uses this inlet because it sucks the hardest. Outlets go to five pairs of jets on pool base.